# Unity3D build error

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-sdk-2.3

Error building Player:

```
Win32Exception: ApplicationName='E:/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20131030/sdk\tools\zipalign.exe',
CommandLine='4 "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folders\Unity exe\bbt - Copy\Temp/StagingArea/Package_unaligned.apk"
"C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Folders\Unity exe\bbt - Copy\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"',
CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'
```

Why am I getting this error? Everything was fine. Suddenly got this error while building.

Comment: Have you updated the eclipse?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It happens when a file can not be found in the correct folder ...sdk\tools\zipalign.exe.

In the yesterday published version of the SDK Tools the file "zipalign" moved from tools folder to build-tools/{version}. Just copy zipalign to "tools" folder and everything should work!

Comment: zipalign.exe is not used on OSX at all.