# Building Player for car game

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, sdk, apk

I am new to Unity and created my first Unity car game for Android. When I try to build the .apk file, it shows me this error:

> Error building Player: Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='C:/Users/Uporabnik/Desktop/Android/adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20140624/sdk\tools\zipalign.exe',
>   CommandLine='4 "C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\New Unity
>   Tutorial1\Temp/StagingArea/Package_unaligned.apk"
>   "C:\Users\Uporabnik\Documents\New Unity
>   Tutorial1\Temp/StagingArea/Package.apk"',
>   CurrentDirectory='Temp/StagingArea'

What do I need to fix?

Comment: Had this exact error and druss's answer below solved the problem

Comment: It kind of hurts when I see paths like `...\Temp/...`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unity3D build error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24466503/unity3d-build-error)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just copy **zipalign.exe** from **build-tools** folder to **tools** folder (as described [here](https://druss.co/2014/07/fixed-error-building-player-win32exception-zipalign-exe-in-unity3d/)).

Answer (score 2):

The same problem i was getting but solution was easy but hard to find, Do this and it will solve.

Just goto your Android SDK folder
Go to build-tools and select a version (e.g.build-tools\22.0.1)
Copy zipalign.exe
Go back to build-tools
Go into tools
Paste zipalign.exe

source:[Error building Player: Win32Exception](http://unity3diy.blogspot.com/2015/08/error-building-player-win32exception.html)

[image]

That's it!

Answer (score 1):

It is basically to do with the location of zipalign.exe check the below link you should be good.

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/cant-build-apk-urgent-help-needed-solved.254106/